# Change content of multiline file into a list

Tags: python, regex, parsing, list

How can I parse through the following file, and turn each line to an element of a list (there is a whitespace at the beginning of each line) ? Unfortunately I've always sucked at regex :/ So turn this:

```
 32.42.4.120', '32.42.4.127
 32.42.5.128', '32.42.5.255
 32.42.15.136', '32.42.15.143
 32.58.129.0', '32.58.129.7
 32.58.131.0', '32.58.131.63
 46.7.0.0', '46.7.255.255
```

into a list :

```
('32.42.4.120', '32.42.4.127'),
('32.42.5.128', '32.42.5.255'),
('32.42.15.136', '32.42.15.143'),
('32.58.129.0', '32.58.129.7'),
('32.58.131.0', '32.58.131.63'),
```

Comment: what happened to the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? (If I am wrong, at least let me know before down-voting)

```
>>> x = [tuple(line.strip().split("', '")) for line in open('file')]
>>> x
[('32.42.4.120', '32.42.4.127'), ('32.42.5.128', '32.42.5.255'), ('32.42.15.136', '32.42.15.143'), ('32.58.129.0', '32.58.129.7'), ('32.58.131.0', '32.58.131.63'), ('46.7.0.0', '46.7.255.255')]
```

Answer (score 1):

no regex needed:

```
l = []

with open("name_file", "r") as f:
   for line in f:
       l.append(line.split(", "))
```

if you want to remove first space and to have tuple you can do:

```
l = []

with open("name_file", "r") as f:
   for line in f:
       data = line.split(", ")
       l.append((data[0].strip(), data[1].strip()))
```

Comment: Missing nit -- he's got leading whitespace, so it needs to be line.strip().split()

Answer (score 1):

```
l = []
f = open("test_data.txt")
for line in f:
 elems = line[1:-1].split("', '")
 l.append((elems[0], elems[1]))
f.close()

print l
```

**Output:**

> [('32.42.4.120', '32.42.4.127'), ('32.42.5.128', '32.42.5.255'), ('32.42.15.136', '32.42.15.143'), ('32.58.129.0', '32.58.129.7'), ('32.58.131.0', '32.58.131.63'), ('46.7.0.0', '46.7.255.25')]